# Pandas/Python/Dropna: Renaming header column names after a dropna takes place with intention to import to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

With the code below, I've successfully removed rows where values may be blank in my CSV file, which consists of 33 columns.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

data = pd.read_csv('TestCSV.csv', sep=',')
data.dropna()
data.dropna().to_csv('CleanCSV.csv', index=False)
```

Now, the intention is to rename the 33 header columns within the file to my own, to then to import the contents of the new (with the newly named headers) into my MySQL database with the following code, which is missing the renaming of the headers:

```
data = pd.read_csv('CleanCSV.csv', sep=',')
cnx = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost:3306/schema', echo=False)
data.to_sql(name='t_database', con=cnx, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I've read up slightly on DataFrames but is this option still valid for when the contents is in a CSV file?  If so, how do I assign the newly dropna's contents to a DataFrame and from there, rename the headers of the columns, after which I intend to import to MySQL?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you create the new csv, do this

```
new_df = data.dropna().rename(columns={'oldcol1': 'newcol1', 'oldcol2': 'newcol2})
```

The `columns` argument is a dictionary with key and values as old and new column names respectively.

Comment: Thank you this worked, one slight typo on your code, replacing the square bracket ] for ' after newcol2.   Out of curiousity, is there a more efficient way to do this?  I realize my newly named columns must be manually entered, however what about the original ones?

Comment: Although not entirely sure if most efficient, I answered my own secondary question by using list:                                                                                                   
new_df = data.dropna().rename(columns={list(data)[0]: 'newcol1, list(data)[1]: 'newcol2', list(data)[2]: 'newcol3'})

Comment: `dataframe.rename` is the standard way of renaming columns. If you want to avoid entering the new names manually, you have to collect those programatically from another source. Where do you get the new column names from?

Comment: You didn't complete your comment and I mistakenly upvoted it :)

Comment: And now to replace newcol1, 2, 3, etc... I've created my own list tied to variable col and listed off all the 33 new column names I want and replaced the manually entered column name with the ones from the col variable by calling the same way.

Comment: I appear to be stuck again as my 'solution' to my secondary question is not working.  I get an Index out of range when I call more than 7 of these list retrievals.  I have 33 columns.

Comment: Are you sure there are more than 7 columns in the dataframe - `data`? 
`data.columns.tolist()` is the standard way of retrieving column names of a dataframe.

Comment: That's what it was..my test file only had 7 columns.  Thanks!